# C# client/server web proxy

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy, tcplistener, http-proxy

I want to implement a client/server web proxy like this:

[image]

I set the proxy in web browser as 127.0.0.1:8080. I want catch every tcp request and send it to a server and get the response of that request and send it back to client. for example my client request is https://www.google.com and client send it to server and server get it's page and send it back to client and client can see google.com in the browser. how can I implement this? Is there any open-source project like this?

```
var tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8080);
tcpListener.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
var result = (IAsyncResult)tcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(RespCallback, tcpListener);
//...
//???
```

Comment: Try this code project : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137979/Simple-HTTP-Server-in-C

Comment: You wan't to implement an Http Proxy. [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/) is open source. Otherwise it is not a simple task to implement on your own.